# Issue using Resolve In AngularJS Routes

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to set config data from a `config.json` file in the same way as shown in this [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/aFFU726uoD5i9Hq83x3N?p=preview)

I've created my own [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/7h7TtrnwhPqfQEQy6mdh?p=preview) which shows the issue I'm having.  The error on my plnkr is:

`Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: myDataProvider <- myData <- hotelsCtrl`

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Can you make a plunker that reproduces your problem? The offending code you posted is incomplete and and seems like it would work if you added the closing  `)`.

Comment: Maybe you are loading the controller in another route without resolving? you need to post more code...

Comment: Think this maybe a JSON/JSONP issue.  I've changed the json file which was named config.js previously, now its config.json - my bad.  Now getting: 
`SyntaxError: missing ; before statement
"Application": "bht",`

Comment: I've added my a plnkr that shows the problem I'm getting.  Any further help with this would be great.

Answer (score 0):

Sorted it, see this [plnker](http://plnkr.co/edit/7h7TtrnwhPqfQEQy6mdh?p=preview)

Just needed a route template and ng-view in the index.html page.

```
        .config(["$routeProvider", function($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider
            .when("/", {
                templateUrl: "main.html",
                controller: "hotelsCtrl",
                controllerAs: "controller",
                resolve: {
                    myData: ["httpDataLoader", function(httpDataLoader){
                        return httpDataLoader.load();
                    }]
                }
            })
    }])
```